# Node JS, Ideas on Template For PDF Creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

How to create PDF Documents in Node.JS.? Is there any better solution to manage templates for different types of PDF creation.

I am using `PDFKit` to create PDF Documents and this will be server side using Javascript. I can not use HTML to create PDF. It will blob of paragraphs and sections with replacing tags with in.

Does anyone know Node.js has any npm package that can deal templates with paragraphs sections headers.

Something like 
`getTemplateByID()` returns a template that contains sections , headers, paragraphs and then i use to replace appropriate tags within the template.

Comment: Why is this tagged angularjs..?

Comment: I am sorry,  thought there may be some solution to deal with these in Front End using Angular and getting data from web api from backend. Sorry it was not intentionally done.

Comment: Your question is *"How to create PDF Documents in Node.JS.?"* and node is backend... then why are you looking for frontend solutions... If you're unsure whether to do this in frontend or backend etc, then you should research and finalize something first...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have to get my HTML template from my database (PostgreSQL) stocked as stream. I request the db to get my template and I create a tmp file.

Inside my template, I have AngularJS tags so I compile this template with datas thanks to the 'ng-node-compile' module:

```
var ngCompile        = require('ng-node-compile');
var ngEnvironment    = new ngCompile();
var templateHTML     = getTemplateById(id);

templateHTML         = ngEnvironment.$compile(templateHTML)(datas);
```

Now I have my compiled template (where you can set your paragraph etc.) and I convert them into PDF thanks to a PhantomJS module 'phantom-html-to-pdf'

```
var phantomHTML2PDF = require('phantom-html-to-pdf')(options);
phantomHTML2PDF(convertOptions, function (error, pdf) {
    if(error) console.log(error);
        // Here you have 'pdf.stream.path' which is your tmp PDF file
        callback(pdf);
    });
```

Now you have your compiled and converted template (pdf), you can do whatever you want ! :)

Useful links:

- https://github.com/MoLow/ng-node-compile
- https://github.com/pofider/phantom-html-to-pdf

I hope this help !